# how to change textcolor of text input edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, material-components-android

I have been using `TextInputEditText` with `TextInputLayout`. I want to change the color of `TextInputEditTextbut` it doesn't work. (Only preview text color changes, i set preview text programitacallyy, but text input edit text color not changing)

below is my xml file

```
<style name="EditTextBaseStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="editTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

layout file

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_8dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/gray3"
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/transparent"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
            app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
            app:expandedHintEnabled="true"
            app:hintTextColor="@color/gray3"
            tools:hint="Hint text">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/value"
                android:textAppearance="@style/EditTextBaseStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@null"
                android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_text_medium"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/b1" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add below line in your style.xml file under resources

```
<style name="EditTextTheme" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#400060AB</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#0060AB</item>
</style>
```

> Add below code in your layout xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/et_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#516CDC"
    android:hint="Enter something here"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/et_input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textColor="#0060AB"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

> Output

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: it is not working

Comment: @nesibeyyubov are you getting any errors? Please check your build.gradle(Module level) has this added or not.  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'

Answer (score 0):

Do it simply like this

```
    editText.setTextColor(color);
```

OR

```
editText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#f454f"));
```